# How to maximize or minimize Syncfusion Tileview item manually

Tags: winrt-xaml, syncfusion

I am working on Windows8 app using Syncfusion controls.I used two Tileview controls in a xaml Usercontrol.What i want is When one Tileview item is maximized, all items in other tileview should be minimized and viceversa.

Selection changed event is firing but i want to know how to minimize or maximize item manually.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of State property to maximize or minimize TileViewItems.
Sample code:

```
 private void TileView_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(tileView1.MaximizedItem!=null)
        {
           tileView2.MaximizedItem.State=TileViewItemState.Normal;
        }
        else if(tileView2.MaximizedItem!=null)
        {
           tileView1.MaximizedItem.State=TileViewItemState.Normal;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I need to control the items in another Tileview..Suppose i have two tileviews 1.LiveTasks 2.Pending Tasks.If i maximize item in LiveTasks means all the items in Pending Tasks must be in minimized state..